# Linear Algebra - verify if the set of solutions is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Without solving the following differential equations verify if the set of solutions is a
vector space
$$f^{''}(x)=x $$

I think that I'm supposed to use use the vector subspace test, but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach or, if so, how to use the test.

Comment: It is the correct approach.  Hint : if $f$ solves the equation does its multiple with any constant solve it, too ?

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that the set of solutions is a subset of $\mathbb P^3.$  Differentiation is a linear transformation.  If the solution set is a vector space, then for all $u, v$ such that $D^2(u) = x$ and $D^2(v) = x$ then $D^2(u+v) = x$

Comment: Can you show that $L\colon C^2(\Bbb R) \to C(\Bbb R)$ given by $L(f) = {\rm Id} - f''$ is a linear operator? The solution space is the kernel of $L$, which is manifestly a vector subspace of $C^2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @IvoTerek . I thought we are looking at the ODE $x-f''(x)=0$ , but I interpret $L$ as $f-f''=0$. ***Sorry*** I was wrong. You just wanted to give another nice hint.

Comment: @Kurt No, you're right, my notation could have been more precise and it was a sloppy mistake. For OP: if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are solutions, is $f_1+f_2$ a solution?